# How to automate sorting of data that evolves based on a a few keywords

Tags: python, excel, sorting, automation, openpyxl

I currently have a task where I receive an excel file with a bunch of records. One of the fields of each record is a summary(usually 100 words long) in text that describes the current record.

My job is to go through these individually and sort them into pre-defined categories based on the summary also write the category back into the file at a different cell of the same line. The sorting is based on a few keywords in the summary, usually each category has a few keywords corresponding to it. The excel file also contains about 15000 rows with previous records and their categories.

I am trying to write a python script to automate this process. I was wondering what would be the best way to tackle this problem efficiently?

Few things to keep in mind -

1. The summary usually has a bunch of other unimportant stuff, so will require to be cleaned up
2. The summary of each record is different even if they belong to the same category, there are only a few similarities which are used for categorization.

My process SO far-

1. create a list of keywords data structure for each category.
2. for each summary count the # of occurrences of words and save that as well as a data structure for each record.
3. Run a process to compare the occurrences with the each category, this step will also calculate a score.
4. Store the scores in a self sorting data structure.
   I'm assuming at this point the category will be with the most frequent keywords of that category.

[image: Mock Example of CSV]

Comment: Would you consider writing a mock csv file similar to your big excel file, but much smaller, and include that example in your question?

Comment: Added a picture of the CSV, hope that helps